# Can't import a python file on iOS using the app pythonista

Tags: python, ios, pythonista

I tried importing without the .py file extension ex: import something. That doesen't work. I also tried turning it into a package by creating a **init**.py but it still doesn't want to import. Oh and by the way I'm using Python 3.5 . Edit: I'm using pythonista and at the moment do not have access to a computer and/or Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pythonista the Documents folder is not in sys.path by default.  The site-packages folder is, or the path of the current script you are running.  If you try to `import foo` from the console, this will fail unless the path that contains foo.py is on sys.path.

You have three basic options:
   1) put your "libraries" into site-packages (found from Modules & Templates, but really the path is ~/Documents/site-packages)

2) Specifically add the path before import, such as if you have foo.py inside Documents/somefolder

```
sys.path.append(os.expanduser('~/Documents/somefolder'))
import foo
```

(though you should first check if the path is in sys.path so you don't get duplicates)

3) Use `impprtlib.find_module`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know you could do this on iOS but I found a fix from another user. This code is not mine but it is sorin's.

```
import os, sys, inspect
# realpath() will make your script run, even if you symlink it :)
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(    inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))
if cmd_folder not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, cmd_folder)

# use this if you want to include modules from a subfolder
cmd_subfolder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0],"subfolder")))
if cmd_subfolder not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, cmd_subfolder)

# Info:
# cmd_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # DO NOT USE __file__ !!!
# __file__ fails if script is called in different ways on Windows
# __file__ fails if someone does os.chdir() before
# sys.argv[0] also fails because it doesn't not always contains the path
```